# How to fix SimpleQueue error when importing the Laspy module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, laspy

When importing Laspy I get the following error:

`import laspy as lp`

ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleQueue'

The error occurs in the following line of the Laspy module:
`from queue import Queue, SimpleQueue`

I tried updating Python because it was likely to be a version issue, but this did not work. Then I tried updating Laspy, conda and lastly I updated everything. This did not work. I am using these versions:
python: 3.6.13
laspy: 2.3.0 (25/10/2022)

(I am working in Jupyter Notebook.)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SimpleQueue` is new in Python 3.7.](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/queue.html#queue.SimpleQueue)

You'll need to use Python 3.7 or newer to use `laspy` – and you should, anyway, since Python 3.6's end-of-life was 1 year and 3 months ago (23 Dec 2021).

Alternately, you can downgrade `laspy` to a version that does support Python 3.6; according to [this commit](https://github.com/laspy/laspy/commit/56efae56d6d9c6da991bed316e1ffc7d607586a2) versions older than 2.2.0 should be compatible.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that conda does not automatically update the python version, so even though I told it to "conda update python", it did not install a newer version. I installed an earlier version of Laspy and it works!